# how to change image upload tab section name in magento 2

Tags: magento2, backend

I want to change "image and video" tab name to "image and documents" and add some custom code to upload documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the text of "**Images And Videos**" by overwrite this file into Your theme folder.

```
vendor/magento/module-product-video/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_form.xml
```

2nd way change the name from CSV file. Copy csv into your theme and make changes according to your requirement.

```
vendor/magento/module-product-video/i18n/en_US.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to change the tab name is to use **`translate inline`** feature of Magento. To translate inline:

1. Login to the admin panel and go to **Stores** > **Configuration**.
2. Navigate to **Advanced (Developer)** menu and click on **Translate Inline** section.
3. Change the value of **Enabled for Admin** to **yes** and click on **Save Config** button at the top right corner.
4. Now go to **Catalog** > **Products** and then navigate to any product.
5. You will see a **`book`** sign on mouse over on any translatable text. Click on that book symbol to open translation popup.
6. Change the translation and save.
7. Refresh the page to see the action in effect.

[image: translate inline]

Comment: Great! i will try this way also